# How to remove the required field for email in user edit view in sugar ce

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I need to remove the required attribute field for email address field for User module (while editing or creating record). I have checked in Studio but its not there. 
How to remove its required attribute in SUgarCRM CE(community Edition).

Comment: why you want remove it? in creating a user it is needed in sending the temporary password.

Comment: password can be created while creating users itself

Answer (score 0):

check editviewdefs.php and detailviewdef.php (first in custom directory and then default module folder)

There you will find all panels fields. Just remove it from proper index.

Answer (score 0):

Email Address is used to generate/send  password when you crate new user It also used in case of forget password .If you want to remove require attribute for Email address you need to configure your config.php file under password setting .

```
  'SystemGeneratedPasswordON' => '0',
    'forgotpasswordON' => false,

     This is working fine my side.
```